# How do I move vertices from the center without scaling?

Tags: transforms

I want to move a vertex from a 3D Cursor in a direction (vertex - center) ie from the cetner outwards.

I know I can achieve that with scaling the vertex position against the 3D cursor, but when moving the vertex by 1 unit I have to deduce the unit from distance.

[image]

When the vertex is 3 units from the 3D cursor and I want to move it by 1 unit. I have to scale the vertex by 1.3333...

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Select vertex, press **G** twice and input the desired value.

Comment: If I understand the feature correctly. Pressing G twice will in case of circle just move the vertices clock-wise or counter-clock-wise. I need to move the vertice from the center outwards.

Comment: Blender being a mesh based 3D modeller is very lacking in this sort of precision modeling area. I'll try and think of something, but I don't think there is any easy way to do this currently.

Comment: If you only want to move the vertex inwards, you can use the *Inset* operator, if you don't mind the extra step of creating a temporary face with `F` then erasing all the surplus created geometry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> command, then type the desired value.
[image]

Comment: Didn't know about this, very useful. This is why a love BSE :)

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos your comment with the *Inset* concept inspired me to find this solution :). I didn't understand what the OP really wanted before you posted it.

Comment: This is perfect. Is is possible to lock the movement to an axis, similar to normal transform ?

Comment: @Melon Therapy I'm affraid it's not possible. Remember that my answer isn't a proper solution but some kind of workaround.